# How to modify a code acceding to a function?

Tags: r

I will try to explain my problem. There are 365 (global map)files in two directories dir1 and dir2, which have the same format ,byte,extend,etc. I computed the `bias` between two datasets using the function and code given below as follows:

How can I solve this problem?please

Comment: The following works for me in R 3.0.1/64 bit on Mac: `x <- array(dim=c(1440,720,300,3))` without problems (it takes some time to allocate the memory). May be your system doesn't allow you to allocate that much memory. What R version / platform are you on?

Comment: Note that you want to allocate an array of 933M floats, that requires 3.7Gb of continuous memory. If you are on a 32-bit system, I doubt it will allow it.

Comment: could you please run `sessionInfo()` and post the results here? Please also note that "64 bit RStudio" is not the same as using the underlying 64-bit R, details are explained here: http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/versions_of_r

Comment: On a 32-bit memory system, you cannot use more than 2G. Therefore, an array with the size 1440 * 720 * 800 * 3 = 2,488,320,000 cannot be allocated, and R determines that at the time of array creation, without even trying to allocate the memory first. When you tried to reduce 800 to 600, the array size becomes 1.87 billion, so it passes this particular check but still fails to allocate the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to memory limitations on a 32-bit system. You want to allocate an array of 933M doubles, that requires 7.6Gb of *continuous* memory. I suggest you to read `?Memory` and `?"Memory-limits"` for more details. In particular, the latter says:

> Error messages beginning ‘cannot allocate vector of size’ indicate
>        a failure to obtain memory, either because the size exceeded the
>        address-space limit for a process or, more likely, because the
>        system was unable to provide the memory.  Note that on a 32-bit
>        build there may well be enough free memory available, but not a
>        large enough contiguous block of address space into which to map
>        it.

If this is indeed your problem, you may look into `bigmemory` package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) which allows to manage massive matrixes with shared and file-based memory. There are also other strategies (e.g. using an SQLite database) to manage data that doesn't fit in memory all at once.

**Update**. Here is an excerpt from [Memory-limit](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) for Windows:

> The address-space limit is 2Gb under 32-bit Windows unless the OS's default has been changed to allow more (up to 3Gb). See http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/server/PAE/PAEmem.mspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473(VS.85).aspx. Under most 64-bit versions of Windows the limit for a 32-bit build of R is 4Gb: for the oldest ones it is 2Gb. The limit for a 64-bit build of R (imposed by the OS) is 8Tb.
>
> It is not normally possible to allocate as much as 2Gb to a single vector in a 32-bit build of R even on 64-bit Windows because of preallocations by Windows in the middle of the address space.
>
> Under Windows, R imposes limits on the total memory allocation available to a single session as the OS provides no way to do so: see memory.size and memory.limit.

Comment: You physical memory doesn't matter; what matters is whether your R version is 32bit or 64bit. Given your last error (cannot allocate vector of size 7Gb) I still think you're using 32-bit R behind your 64-bit R-Studio.